# Java MultiThreading Stop Method

Tags: java, multithreading

What will happen if we access a thread which was stopped using stop() method.

```
 UserThread t = new UserThread();
  t.start();
  System.out.println(t.getName());
  System.out.println(t.getState());
  t.stop();
  System.out.println(t.getState());
```

Anyhow stop() method is deprecated in java8, but need the output for above. Is it possible to access the thread which was stopped means in terminated state?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is Thread.stop deprecated?**

> Because it is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread causes it to unlock
>   all the monitors that it has locked. (The monitors are unlocked as the
>   ThreadDeath exception propagates up the stack.) If any of the objects
>   previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state,
>   other threads may now view these objects in an inconsistent state.
>   Such objects are said to be damaged. When threads operate on damaged
>   objects, arbitrary behavior can result. This behavior may be subtle
>   and difficult to detect, or it may be pronounced. Unlike other
>   unchecked exceptions, ThreadDeath kills threads silently; thus, the
>   user has no warning that his program may be corrupted. The corruption
>   can manifest itself at any time after the actual damage occurs, even
>   hours or days in the future.

**What should I use instead of Thread.stop?**

> Most uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some
>   variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The
>   target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from
>   its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it
>   is to stop running. To ensure prompt communication of the
>   stop-request, the variable must be volatile (or access to the variable
>   must be synchronized).

For example, suppose your applet contains the following start, stop and run methods:

```
private Thread blinker;

public void start() {
    blinker = new Thread(this);
    blinker.start();
}

public void stop() {
    blinker.stop();  // UNSAFE!
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

You can avoid the use of Thread.stop by replacing the applet's stop and run methods with:
    private volatile Thread blinker;

```
public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}

public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in seeing what is the state of a thread after you call `stop` you can suppress the deprecation warning by adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` before your test class definition.
For instance try the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
class test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Thread t = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            while(true) {
               try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
               }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
         }
      };
      t.start();
      System.out.println(t.getName());
      System.out.println(t.getState());
      t.stop();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for stop to take effect
      }catch(Exception e) {}
      System.out.println(t.getState());
   }
}
```

Spoiler alert: the status is `TERMINATED`

Answer (score 0):

Its advised not use stop() method in Thread class since this is deprecated.

If you want to abort the thread execution use interrupt()

```
class IntThread extends Thread{  
public void run(){  
try{  
Thread.sleep(1000);  
System.out.println("Didn't Interrupt me !!!");  
}catch(InterruptedException e){  
throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..."+e);  
}  

}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
IntThread t1=new IntThread();  
t1.start();  
try{  
t1.interrupt();  
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);}  

}  
}
```

You can refer [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for more details about interrupt.